# When prepositions are consecutively used in sentences

Tags: prepositions, as

There is a sentence.

> the image of green consumerism as associated in the past with more
> eccentric members of society has virtually disappeared.

It meant

> The image of green consumerism has virtually disappeared. Because
> the image was related with eccentric members of society in
> the past.

Or

> The image of green consumerism related with eccentric eccentric
> members of society in the past has virtually disappeared.

I don't know how to translate sentences. When prepositions are used like that 'as associated in the past with more eccentric members'

I do not get what 'with clause' decorates in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence doesn't mean the same thing as *either* of the rephrased versions.

The first rephrased version is the most wrong, because the original says nothing about reasons of any kind, it just states a fact.

However, the second is also wrong, because the original doesn't mention eccentric members of society of the past, but past *associations* of green consumerism with eccentric members of society.

---

If you want a rephrased version of the original sentence, consider the following:

> What has virtually disappeared today is the past association of the image of green consumerism with more eccentric members of society.

---

Simplifying it significantly, at the risk of leaving out some meaning, the following could be said:

> Today, we seldom associate green consumerism with eccentric behaviour.

Or:

> Buying and eating vegan, vegetarian, and organic foods is now considered normal.